# Multithreading in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It is necessary to speed up the work of the program using multithreading. This script adds a grid of tiles according to a 2D array. But when the grid is large, a frieze occurs. I really ask for your help, since multithreading is difficult for me. Especially in Unity.

```
using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class GridGenerationSprite : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Sprite mySprite;
        private SpriteRenderer sr;
    
        [SerializeField] SettingGeneration settingGeneration;
    
        [SerializeField] float tileSize;
    
        [SerializeField]  int size;
    
        private float xDir;
        private float yDir;
    
        private void Start()
        {
            StartCoroutine(StartGreed());
        }
    
        IEnumerator StartGreed()
        {
                yield return new Grid(size, tileSize, xDir, yDir, settingGeneration, transform);
        } 
        class Grid 
        {
            private byte[,] cells;
            private float xDir;
            private float yDir;
    
            public Grid(int size, float tileSize, float xDir, float yDir, SettingGeneration settingGeneration, Transform transform) 
            {
                List<GameObject> listG = new List<GameObject>();
                cells = settingGeneration.startSetting(size);
                for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
                    for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
                    {
    
                        GameObject referenceTile = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load(cells[x, y].ToString()));
    
                        listG.Add(referenceTile);
    
                        GameObject tile = (GameObject)Instantiate(referenceTile, transform);
    
                        tile.name = $"X: {x} Y: {y}";
    
                        float posX = y * tileSize;
                        float posY = -x * tileSize;
    
                        tile.transform.position = new Vector2(posX, posY);
                    }
                for (int i = 0; i < listG.Count; i++)
                {
                    GameObject go = listG[i];
                    Destroy(go);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I understand it. Coroutines don't help.

Comment: Your Coroutine still executes everything within one single frame ... Coroutines have nothing to do with multi threading

Comment: Also why are you instantiating twice per tile? Simply use the first instance right away?

Comment: _"when the grid is large, a frieze occurs"_ - don't generate a large grid then.  You should merely generate what is essential and _stream the rest._

Comment: _[Why coroutines are evil](https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2022/10/06/implementing-time-based-delays-in-unity-3d/)_

Comment: It also seems odd you instantiate a load of objects then destroy them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This code is not multithreaded. Coroutines are asynchronous but not multithreaded; this will not improve your performance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's enough to use *asynchronous* operations (which is not the same that multithreaded but easier to handle and safer)

For that, you can use [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) or [UniTasks](https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask) or [Promises](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.game.foundation@0.4/manual/Promise.html)

However, if you need threads, it's better to learn [.NET threading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/using-threads-and-threading?redirectedfrom=MSDN) at first